# How do I get warnings if jsDoc annotations are missing in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdoc

I am coming from a Java background and I always liked how eclipse warned me when there were classes, methods or properties that lacked javadoc annotations.

Now, since I manage JavaScript projects, I introduced jsDoc which works quite well. However, in order to keep track on documentation I'd like to have those warnings as well for missing jsDoc annotations in eclipse.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, nevermind. I just found the option how to enable it here:

[image: How to enable jsdoc warnings in eclipse]